# Find the common elements of the lists in a list of lists

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

Considering the problem:

> Make a function to find the common elements of the lists in a list of lists.
>
> Example:
>
> common ( [ [1,2,3,3,5,11], [2,2,2,3,3,5], [2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,18,19], [3,5,10,15] ] ) = [3, 5].

I came up with this solution:

```
import Data.List(group, nub, sort)

-- |
-- This function returns the elements common to all lists in a list of lists.
--
commonXss :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
commonXss xss = concat [x | (x, y) <- countElemAppearsXss xss, y == length xss]

-- |
-- This function takes a list of lists and returns a list of tuples. Each tuple
-- (x, y) is made of x == [element] and y == number of lists in which that
-- element appeared.
-- 
countElemAppearsXss :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [([a], Int)]
countElemAppearsXss xss = freq $ sort $ concat $ map nub xss

-- |
-- This function returns a list of tuples. Each tuple (x, y) is made of
-- x == [element] and y == it's frequency.
-- 
freq :: Ord a => [a] -> [([a], Int)]
freq xs = map (\x -> ([head x], length x)) . group . sort $ xs
```

Is there a simpler way, more straightforward way that I'm missing? Perhaps in a library? How about the style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is just a matter of folding using the [`intersect`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=intersect) function of `Data.List`, then deduplicating the result using `nub`.